# CSS :target random #keyword, do something with same div

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I have some links, and each of these have a unique href.

lets say link one have href="#first".
and link two have href="#second".
What would then be the CSS to do something with a div? (with the ID box)

I have tried lots of things like:

```
#first:target #box{
    something..
}
#second:target #box{
    something else..
}
```

`#linkOne:hover #box{ width:200px; }`

This changes the size of #box by hovering #linkOne I want the same to happen with :target, like change the size of #box by clicking the link

Comment: *do something*? Can you elaborate a bit more? Do you want to hide/show them based on `target`?

Comment: What do you mean 'target'?  Are you trying to format each target box?  If so, each ID is enough, so you can just use `#first`, and `#second`.

Comment: What does the HTML look like? `<div><a href="#first"></a></div>`?

Comment: @SableFoste https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:target

Comment: I mean change the size of the div with ID box, with transition, but as i got that to work i didnt mention it

Comment: Why don't you use id or class as identifier? Do you know the use of CSS? What do you mean for "do something"?

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/F6JRt/)?

Comment: #linkOne:hover #box{
 width:200px;
}
This changes the size of #box by hovering #linkOne
I want the same to happen with :target, like change the size of #box by clicking the link

Comment: @user2725580: I think it is better if you make a fiddle.

Comment: Need to see your HTML.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong, you are looking for something like the below. This will set the `height` of the currently targeted element to 20px. Transition effect will also be applied.

**HTML:**

```
<a href='#first'>First</a>
<a href='#second'>Second</a>

<div id='first'>This is first div</div>
<div id='second'>This is second div</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#first, #second {
    height: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: height 1s ease-in;
}
#first:target {
    height: 20px;
}
#second:target {
    height: 20px;
}
```

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F6JRt/)

**EDIT:** I know you haven't tagged jQuery/JavaScript and was looking for a CSS solution. But if you have many such links and are ok to have a JS based solution, you can try the below.

This script has a mapping between the `id` of the link that is clicked and the `height` that the box is supposed to have when the link is clicked. Based on it, the `#box` element's height is modified. Transitions will also work as can be seen in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F6JRt/1/).

```
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].onclick = function(e){
        var box = document.getElementById('box');
        var heights = { first: '20px', second: '40px', third: '30px' };
        if(e.target.id)
            box.style.height = heights[e.target.id];
    };
}
```

Comment: Yes, it is like that, but only with one div.
So that you can adjust the size of one div by clicking on different links

Comment: You mean if you click on first link height should be 20px and when click on second kink height should be 10px or 30px something like that? If yes, I don't think that can be done with pure CSS.

Comment: @user2725580: Check xec's solution. You can use that if you have lesser number of such links. I have also posted a JS based alternative above, just in case you need.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to select the currently targeted element, you can simply do `:target`

### html

```html
<a href="#first">first link</a>
<a href="#second">second link</a>
<div id="first">first div</div>
<div id="second">second div</div>
```

### css

```css
:target {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

The div with the corresponding id of the link clicked will have a red border.

http://jsfiddle.net/wk3rR/2/

## UPDATE

Judging by your comment, it appears you want to manipulate the same box with different current targets, which won't be straight-forward, but can be done if you **nest the `<div>`s** with the IDs and then your original css should work:

```html
<a href="#first">first link</a>
<a href="#second">second link</a>
<div id="first">
    <div id="second">
        <div class="box">box</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### css

```css
#first:target .box {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
#second:target .box {
    border: 1px solid yellow;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wk3rR/3/

Comment: Yep, that is a possibility. But in the case of OP choosing this way, I hope there are only a few such links :)

Comment: @Harry fingers crossed for only two links ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you need the use of [javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) if you want manipulate [DOM](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/). You have to remember CSS is only for style the page, not for making actions with the elements.